# In Swift, Change the location of UITableView Editing Mode checkmarks from the left side to the right side

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

In a UITableView like below... is there an easy way to move the checkmark buttons from the left side of the UITableViewCell to the right side?

[image]

Comment: Make your own checkmarks. You're implementing a custom solution, you will have to handle this as such.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this using `UITableViewCell`'s `accessoryView` like below:

```
cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
cell.accessoryView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)) //You can change to UIButton with your own custom checkmark button 
cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() //change to your color
```